# videojs HLS plugin : how to change the xhr uri

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming

I have been looking every where but couldn't find an answer:

I am using video.js + videojs-HLS plugin to stream playlist.m3u8.

the timeout function within the plugin make a request uri to (for example):

```
localhost:8888/240p_001.ts
```

I need to change this automatically generated uri to (for example) :

```
localhost:8888/streams?id=1&segment=240p_001.ts
```

How ?????

I tried to hook "videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest" with no effect.

Thank you very much !!!!! Please help

Comment: What version? See: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/issues/665

Comment: thank you for your interest. I am using version 5.12.2. I have read this post but couldn't figure out what to do !

Comment: for starters you should post the full `beforeRequest`

Comment: Actually the issue rely here: The file I am trying to stream (ex: 240p.m3u8) is outside of my public folder. So server side the request :"streams?id=1&segment=240p_001.ts" return a header : "content-type : application/x-mpegURL" with the file name. BUT i have this error in videojs-hls : 'Cannot read property 'segments' of undefined'@20425

Comment: In this case check the requests/responses in the  server access logs and the browser's console network tab.

Comment: thanks for your help. If I analize the behaviour of the plugin with a file.m3u8 within my public folder: it first make a request to file.m3u8, then request (timeout) all the segments : file_001.ts, file_002.ts .... with the same URL. What i am trying to achieve is : once the player loaded the file.m3u8 (with setting the 'src')... I want the plugin to request  streams?id=1&segment=file_001.ts (instead of public_folder/file_001.ts) ... how ??

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution ! :

first call "videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest" only when the player is ready.
Inside "beforeRequest" : get the options.uri : see the file is requesting and rewrite your own URL with the same file parameter.

And it works!